# Why no "s" after Tasche?

Tags: gender, genitive, declension

We add an "s" after Restaurant in the following sentence to signify the genitive case:

> Die Preise des Restaurants ist sehr hoch.

But then why don't we add an "s" after Tasche in the below sentence?

> Die Farbe des Tasche ist sehr shön.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These words are declined differently.

"Restaurant" is grammatically neutral gender (sächlich/neutrum):

Nominativ: das Restaurant
Genitiv: des Restaurants

> Die Preise des Restaurants sind sehr hoch.

"Tasche" is grammatically female gender (weiblich/femininum):

Nominativ: die Tasche
Genitiv: der Tasche

> Die Farbe der Tasche ist sehr schön.

So the genitive case is only made clear by the different article. Genitive s is only used for male and neutral nouns in German.

For a more comprehensive picture you can look at a [declension table](http://germanforenglishspeakers.com/nouns/declension-tables/).